# Cycling from last to first (and vice versa) with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have two view controllers, let's call them transmit and receive. They are instantiated from storyboard in my parent view controller's `viewDidLoad`, and the first one is initially added to a `UIPageViewController`.

I've also set up a data source for the page view controller, with the following methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
        viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController class] == [PRTransmitViewController class]) {
        return self.receiveViewController;
    }
    else {
        return self.transmitViewController;
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
        viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController class] == [PRReceiveViewController class]) {
        return self.transmitViewController;
    }
    else {
        return self.receiveViewController;
    }
}
```

My question is: is it OK to arrange an endless cycle like this? As I understand, the currently presented view controller is replaced and the previous one is unloaded. Do you anticipate any memory management problems with this arrangement as the user goes from screen to screen in a loop?

Comment: I think this will work without any bugs/leaks. Why? Because you are not creating new "first" controller each time, and the total number of controllers always stays the same. You can test though with Leaks detector in Instruments app

Comment: Can i ask why you want to do endless loop.?

Comment: @h4cky Sure! This is not a "book" view; it replaces an initial screen where the user has to push either of two buttons to proceed. Now we show the other view as default, and the user can switch between these views with a gesture. With a loop like this, the user can swipe in either direction to switch views; there is no "wrong" direction. It seemed fit to use an existing view controller container.

Comment: Wow, 1,000 views. :-)