# Is UINavigationController fit to pages cycles?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm quite new to iOS development and I am having difficulties trying to understand the `UINavigationController` object. I'm guessing most apps use it to organize all of their windows but I am not sure.

It seems like it is especially useful when the app pages are members of a hierarchy, but my app project won't organize its pages that way. Instead, it will be more like a cycle, for instance with 4 pages:

A -> B ->C ->D -> A.

Is that pattern compatible with `UINavigationController` or do I have to use some alternative?

Comment: A UINavigationController manages a "stack" of view controllers (pages), so it probably isn't appropriate.  You could probably use a UIPageViewController or a UIScrollView with a UIPageController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to push multiple instances of the same controller class onto a UINavigation controller however the structure it maintains is a stack. You cannot reuse the same controller instance multiple times within that stack and every controller in the stack remains in memory. You probably do not want to construct arbitrarily deep stacks as they will be resource intensive and many levels of "back" navigation becomes disorienting.

See [pushViewController:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) which states:

> The view controller to push onto the stack. This object cannot be a tab bar controller. If the view controller is already on the navigation stack, this method throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A `UINavigationController` is not a good idea for building an endless cycle of `UIViewControllers` because a `UINavigationController` behaves like a stack. Every pushed `UIViewController` will be retained and consumes memory. Furthermore it's not (easily) possible to reuse `UIViewControllers` to build up the cycle.

This can be archived with a `UIPageViewController` which allows reusing all your `UIViewControllers`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html

[Cycling from last to first (and vice versa) with UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239868/cycling-from-last-to-first-and-vice-versa-with-uipageviewcontroller)